# Story ID: Time travel story where people swept into the past attract attention by altering a naval battle using tech like a naval ram

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I think it was a novel, but not sure. Some people, from perhaps more than one period (I don't remember for sure) got swept back to the ancient Mediterranean. It's somehow hypothesized that they were drawn along in the time-transport-wake of some time traveler, and if they can cause something massively anachronistic, it'll get attention of the traveler, who can return them to their own times.

Some inventions like outfiting boats' bows with naval rams to turn the tide of a significant battle did the trick, I think.

I think the main character was a male from our time or so. I think one of the other characters was a priestess from Minoan Crete.

I think his would have been from the early 2000s at latest, but could be from 1990s or even decades earlier, if it's a book I picked up from a used book seller. Possibly it was even a novella, short story, or serialized novel in F&SF, Analog, Galaxy SF, or other magazine? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry, I think I found my own answer after googling with some further combinations of terms. *[The Dancer From Atlantis](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/940988.The_Dancer_From_Atlantis)*, by Poul Anderson, 1971.

[image: The Dancer From Atlantis - Book Cover]

> An experiment in the future gone awry...and Duncan Reid, American architect of the 20th century, came out of unconciousness to find himself hopelessly marooned in the far distant past.
>
> Bound to him were three of the strangest humans he had ever encountered... a medieval Russian, and a fourth-century Hun, and a sacred priestess who worshiped him as a god. And all shared the same fate--pulled through a hole in time to a present which was ancient history. Together the quartet formed a strange alliance which none dared break. For not only were their own futures at stake... but the very future of the world they had found....

I did a bunch of googling before but didn't hit upon it until now.

Mention of the ram from Google Books:

> Down the center ran a raised and bulwarked deck, beneath which passed thwarts for the rowers. **The ram** was a beak projecting at the waterline, bronze-sheathed, backed by heavy timbers.