# How many shuttlecraft were lost over the course of Star Trek:Voyager?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

Is there a tally somewhere of the exact number shown to be lost over the entire series, and (where possible) the episodes in which they were lost (or when the audience learned they were lost, if appropriate)?

Possibly complicated by the "Year of Hell" storyline and other cases where there were time resets; please note where a shuttle destroyed in an episode would have (logically, at least) been restored due to a time reset, to get an accurate count of the shuttles destroyed *in the final timeline*.

Comment: Answers there provides a list of shuttle names, and refers to "all fifteen until then destroyed shuttles" by the time of episode "Alice", but it's not clear if the somewhat round "15" is humorous estimate , and that's not the end of the series. It does offer a limit on how many would have been present at a time, however.

Comment: If you're not happy with the quality of the answers on the dupe you have some choices; you can post a bounty, you can prod the answerers with comments to see if they can improve their answers or you can self-answer.

Comment: The answers there are of fine enough quality; they adequately address a different (perhaps more difficult to answer definitively) question: how many shuttles Voyager possessed in total. While the questioner mentioned as context the fact that many were lost, it was *not* actually asked exactly how many were, over the course of the entire series. I've now restricted my question to the first part of my title; the latter part is the one more addressed by the linked Q. "Self-answer"? In other words, "You're annnoying; go re-watch the series yourself and get back to us"? Is that really called for?

Comment: @JacobC. - Self-answering isn't just acceptable, it's positively encouraged across the entire site.

Comment: Fair enough. I've [done it](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/162596/story-id-time-travel-story-where-people-swept-into-the-past-attract-attention-b) on [occasion](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/162600/humans-orbiting-exoplanet-establish-telepathic-control-of-massive-six-legged-fel), but in the present context I took it a bit differently (perhaps mistakenly, sorry). I did now find https://www.quora.com/Approximately-how-many-shuttles-did-the-starship-Voyager-lose-over-the-course-of-the-series ... Is it problematic to copy an answer from Quora, since it's a competing site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Star Trek* fansite Ex Astris Scientia has [a list of shuttles that were lost](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/inconsistencies/inconsistencies-voy.htm) over the course of the series - destroyed outright, given away, or otherwise unrecoverable - along with the episode and cause of loss. As far as I can tell, none of the listed incidents were later erased from time.

They estimate somewhere between 10 and 17 shuttles were lost to the *Voyager* crew, depending on how many of 7 "probably destroyed" shuttles could be salvaged. (They also list 8 that were "badly damaged" but explicitly or presumably recovered.)

([Backup Archive.org link, in case the original vanishes.)](https://web.archive.org/web/20171221063221/http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/inconsistencies/inconsistencies-voy.htm)

Comment: The problem with posting a link-only answer is that if that link goes dead, the answer becomes (relatively) worthless. Perhaps you could shift the relevant bits over here...

Comment: I considered that but to answer the question, I'd basically need to copy the whole table from the linked article. I'm not sure what Stack Exchange's policy is on how long a quote can be but it felt a bit shady to me to just copy the whole thing, even with attribution. For now, I've added an Archive.org link to the December 2017 version of the page, which should at least make it robust against the link dying.

Comment: You'd still do better. Just the name of the shuttle and the episode would add a bunch to this answer